# Reuse parameterized (prepared) SQL Query

Tags: mysql, powershell

i've coded an ActiveDirectory logging system a couple of years ago...
it never become a status greater than beta but its still in use...

i got an issue reported and found out what happening...
they are serveral filds  in such an ActiveDirectory Event witch are UserInputs, so i've to validate them! -- of course i didnt...

so after the first user got the brilliant idea to use singlequotes in a specific foldername it crashed my scripts - easy injection possible...

so id like to make an update using prepared statements like im using in PHP and others.

Now this is a Powershell Script.. id like to do something like this:

```
$MySQL-OBJ.CommandText = "INSERT INTO `table-name` (i1,i2,i3) VALUES (@k1,@k2,@k3)"

$MySQL-OBJ.Parameters.AddWithValue("@k1","value 1")
$MySQL-OBJ.Parameters.AddWithValue("@k2","value 2")
$MySQL-OBJ.Parameters.AddWithValue("@k3","value 3")

$MySQL-OBJ.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

This would work fine - 1 times.
My Script runs endless as a Service and loops all within a `while($true)` loop.

Powershell clams about the param is already set...

> Exception calling "AddWithValue" with "2" argument(s): "Parameter
>   '@k1' has already been defined."

how i can reset this "bind" without closing the database connection?
id like the leave the connection open because the script is faster without closing and opening the connections when a event is fired (10+ / sec)

Example Code
(shortend and not tested)

```
##start
function db_prepare(){
    $MySqlConnection = New-Object MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection
    $MySqlConnection.ConnectionString = "server=$MySQLServerName;user id=$Username;password=$Password;database=$MySQLDatenbankName;pooling=false"
    $MySqlConnection.Open()
    $MySqlCommand = New-Object MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand
    $MySqlCommand.Connection = $MySqlConnection
    $MySqlCommand.CommandText = "INSERT INTO `whatever` (col1,col2...) VALUES (@va1,@va2...)"
}
while($true){
    if($MySqlConnection.State -eq 'closed'){ db_prepare() }

    ## do the event reading and data formating stuff
    ## bild some variables to set as sql param values

    $MySQLCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@va1",$variable_for_1)
    $MySQLCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@va2",$variable_for_2)
    .
    .
    .

    Try{  $MySqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() | Out-Null }
    Catch{ <# error handling #> }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your logic so that the `db_prepare()` method initializes a MySql connection and a MySql command with parameters. [Set the parameter values](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/connector-net/html/M_MySql_Data_MySqlClient_MySqlParameterCollection_SetParameter_1.htm) for [pre-declared parameter names](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/connector-net/html/M_MySql_Data_MySqlClient_MySqlParameterCollection_Add_2.htm) in loop. Like so,

```
function db_prepare(){
    # ...
    # Add named parameters
    $MySQLCommand.Parameters.Add("@val1", <datatype>)
    $MySQLCommand.Parameters.Add("@val2", <datatype>)
}
while($true) {
    # ...
    # Set values for the named parameters
    $MySQLCommand.Parameters.SetParameter("@val1", <value>)
    $MySQLCommand.Parameters.SetParameter("@val2", <value>)
    $MySqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() 
    # ...
}
```

Comment: wow this looks quite logic :D ill test that soon
thank you in advance

Comment: how to specity <datatype>?
i dont found any information for datatype on the reference... just for values.. and next problem:

     
Method invocation failed because [MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlParameter] does not contain a method named 'SetParameter'.

Comment: @DavidBla What version of MySql Connector/Net library are you using?

Comment: [void][system.reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom("C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector Net 6.8.3\Assemblies\v2.0\MySql.Data.dll")

Comment: im free to use any better version :D
and of course i found https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/connector-net/html/T_MySql_Data_MySqlClient_MySqlDbType.htm

Comment: die aktuellste version scheint 6.9 zu sein...
Habe mir die beta MySQL Connector Net 7.0.5 geladen - leider ist dort auch : Method invocation failed because [MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlParameter] does not contain a method named 'SetParameter'.